# Conditionally default to FLV in video.js

Tags: javascript, video, mp4, flv, video.js

Is it possible to make video.js use the fallback flv videos as standard in IE? I can't get mp4 to work in Internet Explorer but flash works as long is there is no mp4 available.

Answer (score 0):

First load the player script/css then we set up our "default" tech order.  After that we use the IE Conditional comments to detect IE and set its tech order.

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6/video.js"></script>
<script>
    var techOrderArr = ["html5", "flash"]; // Default for everyone
</script>
<!--[if IE]><script>
    techOrderArr = ["flash","html5"]; // IE specific
</script><![endif]-->
```

After that, setup your video as normal using the javascript initialization, but include the `techOrder` parameter.

```
<video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
    preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg">
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
<script>
    videojs("MY_VIDEO_1", {
        techOrder: techOrderArr
    });
</script>
```